# How to remove an invalid sequence from a Genbank file containing multiple genome sequences based on ID

Tags: biopython, dna-sequence, genbank

I have a ~3 GB Genbank file containing complete Genbank annotations for ~20,000 bacterial genome sequences. My goal is to use BioPython to parse these sequences, and write individual fasta files for non-duplicate sequences with something like the following:

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
records = SeqIO.parse(r'C:\Users\aaa\aaa\file.gb', 'genbank')
for record in records:
    if seq_name not in organism_dict:
        with open(output_folder + seq_name, 'w') as handle:
            SeqIO.write(record, handle, 'fasta')
```

This works perfectly fine for the first ~2,000 sequences, but then reaches an entry with an invalid footer and produces the error message ValueError: Sequence line mal-formed 'title>NCBI/ffsrv11 - WWW Error 500 Diagnostic'.

I managed to find the sequence causing the error, so what I'd like to do is delete it from my Genbank file and manually download it as a fasta file later. However, I can't open the file in a text editor (due to its size), and I can't parse the file (due to the error), so I'm wondering if anyone has an idea of how to remove a sequence based on Genbank ID. I'm open to non-python options.

Thank you in advance,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Try/Except where the Except writes Record.ID to a seperate file.  If the Try fails it won't write and the Except will collect Record.IDs for later download.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear, but the problem is with the SeqIO.parse() function itself (I just included the rest of the code to give a sense of my goal). Using only the first two lines of code produces the same error